# Which objects are persistent in Java Card, and when?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard

This question is twofold, but hopefully shouldn't be unreasonably long to answer, despite its own length. Feel free to answer only part of it, though, and sorry for making it so exhaustive!

- Which objects are persisted? Which objects are transient?
- When is an object persisted?

For the first part, the question applies to:

- Objects that are stored in an `Applet`
- Objects that are transitively stored in an `Applet`
- Objects that are only stored in stack variables (not referenced, even transitively, from any `Applet`)
- Objects that are stored in an array built with `makeTransientObjectArray`
- Objects that are transitively stored in an array build with `makeTransientObjectArray` (eg. stored in a member variable of an object stored in a `makeTransientObjectArray`)

For the second part, it applies depending on the answer of the first question. For instance:

- I assume objects that are directly stored in a transient object array are not persisted. In this case and assuming objects on the stack are persisted, when does the object stored there become not-persisted? Is it persisted at the `new Object` and un-persisted when being put into the transient object array?
- If an object has references from both a transient object array and an applet, and the applet reference is erased, is the object un-persisted?

Thank you in advance!

---

I have looked into the JCRE specification v2.2.2 (the version I'm using), but there are points that are unclear in it (hence the exhaustiveness of this question, as I feel this is more appropriate for a Q/A-style forum):

- Page 2-2 mentions that the JCRE makes an object persistent when it's transitively stored in an `Applet`. However, Glossary-7 states that objects are persistent by default. The difference may seem non-observable, but affects the need to garbage-collect or not when a card power cycle is needed anyway.
- Page 5-1 states that the fields of a transient object must never be stored in persistent memory. But it doesn't state whether this is also true for objects transitively in a transient object array, eg. objects stored in fields of objects in a transient object array.
- Page 5-1, same statements, may conflict with page 2-2, when an object has a reference to it stored both in a transient object array and in an `Applet`.

These three questions are respectively equivalent to:

- part 1 bullet points 3 and 5 (and, depending on the answer, part 2 bullet point 1)
- part 1 bullet point 5
- part 2 bullet point 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Q**: *Which objects are persisted? Which objects are transient?*

All object instance fields are persistent when they are created using `new`. Objects created by the JRE may not be: you'd have to check the Java Card or OS documentation to find out. Note that fields to other objects are *references*. Those references themselves may point to arrays in transient memory or to other objects that contain volatile state.

Arrays are transient if they have been created or defined as being transient (usually by calling `makeTransientXxxArray()`). They are persistent when they are created using `new`.

> **Q**: *When is an object persisted?*

Upon creation or during any update. Generally the persistent values are simply put in persistent memory: flash or EEPROM. Any write to flash or EEPROM is persisted directly. Note that the Java Card transaction mechanism can still *roll back* changes to persistent memory.

This is very different from Java SE where objects instances are stored in RAM, and therefore need to be persisted *after creation and each update* (if they are persisted at all).

> **Q:** *For the first part, the question applies to: ...*

No, now you're making it unnecessarily complex. The fields of an object are always persisted. How they are *referred to* doesn't matter.

The *reference itself* may not be persistent, even if the object is. It may be in a transient object array or local variable for instance. If all references are lost then the object cannot be accessed anymore and it becomes eligible for garbage collection. But before it is collected it will still remain in persistent memory.

> *I assume objects that are directly stored in a transient object array are not persisted. In this case and assuming objects on the stack are persisted, when does the object stored there become not-persisted? Is it persisted at the new Object and un-persisted when being put into the transient object array?*

Consider the previous answer. There is really no such thing as a "transient object array". What exists is an array that consists of *references* to other objects. These references may be transient or persistent. The objects referenced may be transient (arrays) or contain references to transient values.

Objects themselves generally *do not convert from persistent to transient or vice versa*. They don't care how they are referenced. They only care if their reference count doesn't become zero, because then they are lost and eligible for garbage collection. This is of course more likely if they are just referenced by a volatile reference in a transient object array or in a local variable.

The stack itself is always in transient memory. It includes all local variables (including parameters and return values). But again: it doesn't contain any objects: it may just contain *transient references* to objects *on the heap*. If those references are lost then the object may be garbage collected.

---

Notes:

- I'm just talking about *classic* Java Card here;
- Java Cards generally don't run the Garbage Collector automatically - normally you have to call [`JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/JCSystem.html#requestObjectDeletion()) to run it, and then it usually runs during startup where it can take a lot of time;
- Java Card also contains special objects such as the APDU buffer which has it's own life cycle;
- Generally you will always use *persistent references* to point to objects, as you don't want to garbage collection to run on Java Card unless at exceptional circumstances.   - Transient arrays are zero'd when they are referenced after a reset. The OS (should) make sure that they are always available.
- The `CLEAR_ON_RESET` arrays keep their contents even if other applets are available. But *this means that the other applets cannot reuse that transient memory, and applets are notoriously RAM starved*. Therefore you should default to `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` transient arrays unless `CLEAR_ON_RESET` functionality is required for *context switches*.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand correctly, this means that there is no way to have a custom object that is not persisted on disk, given there are only `makeTransientXXXArray`, and no `newTransient` keyword. Which means that every new object creation will take garbage collection space, even when never referenced from a persistent location… well, that's a bit sad.

Anyway, thank you for your precise answer!

Comment: You are correct. However, there is no "disk" and the garbage collection space is called "the heap" :) I sometimes make jokes to my colleagues of adding a disk, RAM slots or active cooling.

Comment: What about static fields(class fields)? Are they saved to nvm memory? So, for example, if I set a static byte filed a = 5, then, reload the card, I still get the value 5?

Comment: Yes, of course they are located in NVM (saved seems to indicate a specific action, which is not really the case). Beware that generally you should try and not use `static` fields. Note that `private static final` fields are actually inlined into the bytecode when using Java Card. Whatever you do, don't try and *update* class fields, let alone arrays. Updating statically stored arrays can trigger some interesting issues on Java Card. For Java Card applet's you always have an object instance: the applet itself, so why not use that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very nice document, freely downloadable from oracle.com, titled "Java Card 3 Platform Runtime Environment Specification"

Comment: I had already searched the spec, and had not found the answer I looked for. I had not put it in the original question, though, as I felt this didn't fit the Q&A format. I've now updated my question to reflect this research. Hopefully you can point me to somewhere more precise in the spec :)